# Is $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz$ reducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$?

Tags: complex-analysis, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

In an exercise, I have the polynomial $p(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz$, I have to decide whether is reducible or not in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.

I think it's reducible, and thinking of it in $\mathbb{C}[y,z][x]$ I have $p(x,y,z)=x^2-x(y+z)+y^2+z^2-yz$.

Applying Bhaskara I get

$\begin{align*} x_{\pm}&=\frac{y+z\pm \sqrt{y^2+2yz+z^2-4y^2-4z^2+4yz}}{2}\\ 
&=\frac{y+z\pm \sqrt{-3(y-z)^2}}{2}\\&=\frac{y+z\pm i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2}\end{align*}$.

But when I try to verify $(x-x_+)(x-x_-)$ (with Wolfram Alpha) I don't get the original polynomial.

Is it wrong using Bhaskara to try to reduce the polynomial?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Works for me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+%28x-%28y%2F2+%2B+z%2F2+%2B+sqrt%28-3%29*y%2F2+-+sqrt%28-3%29*z%2F2%29%29+%28x+-+%28y%2F2+%2B+z%2F2+-+sqrt%28-3%29*y%2F2+%2B+sqrt%28-3%29*z%2F2%29%29)

Comment: Maybe my input was wrong, I plug in $(x - \frac {y + z + \sqrt{3} i(y - z)}{2}) (x - \frac{y + z - \sqrt{3} i(y - z)}{2})$ but I don't get the answer. I suppose I could've checked it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

\begin{align*}
(x-x_+)(x-x_-)&=\left(\frac{2x-y-z}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{i\sqrt3(y-z)}2\right)^2\\
&=\frac{4x^2+y^2+z^2-4xy-4xz+2yz+3(y^2+z^2-2yz)}4\\
&=x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

The theorem, going back to the time of Ludwig Otto Hesse, is that a quadratic form in three variables factors as the product of two linears over the complexes if and only if the determinant of the Hessian matrix is zero.

If you start with that attitude, you can just demand that the coefficients of $x$ are both $1$ and see what happens. 
$$ \left(x + A y + B z \right)  \left(x + C y + D z \right)$$ 
To get the squares correct,
$$ \left(x + A y + B z \right)  \left(x + \frac{1}{A} y + \frac{1}{B} z \right)$$
Now we need the mixed terms to have coefficients $-1,$ so
$$ A + \frac{1}{A} = -1.  $$
Stay with this,
$$  A^2 + 1 = -A $$
$$ A^2 + A + 1 = 0 $$
So $A$ is a nontrivial cube root of unity.
Naming $$  \omega = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt 3}{2}  $$ so
 $$  \omega^2 = \frac{-1 - i \sqrt 3}{2}  $$
  we reach
$$  \left(x +  y \omega +  z \omega^2 \right) \left(x + y \omega^2  +  z \omega \right) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy $$

Page from a relevant article by Brookfield:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This following was inspired by Will Jagy's answer.

It is well known that over the real $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz$ can be factored as $$(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx ).$$

Note that $$F:=x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz$$ $$=x^3+(\omega y)^3+(\omega^2 z)^3-3x(\omega y)(\omega^2 z)$$
$$=x^3+(\omega^2 y)^3+(\omega z)^3-3x(\omega^2 y)(\omega z),$$ where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity.

It follows that $F$ also has factors $x+\omega y+\omega^2 z$ and $x+\omega^2 y+\omega z$. Since ${\mathbb C}[x,y,z]$ is a UFD, one has $$F=(x+y+z)(x+\omega y+\omega^2 z)(x+\omega^2 y+\omega z),$$ as required. QED

Comment: Good. There is a theorem, proved first about 1849 and not by Hesse. A homogeneous cubic in three variables, there is an if-and-only-if for completely factoring over the complexes: The entries of the Hessian matrix $H$ are linear homogeneous. The determinant of $H$ is therefore homogeneous cubic. If this determinant is a constant times the original $F,$ then $F$ factors completely over the complexes. More difficult example at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678486/how-to-show-that-if-x-y-z-are-rational-numbers-satisfying-x-y-z3-9/2678675#2678675

Comment: I added a page from Brookfield's paper to my answer, as a jpeg. Year 2016, author Gary Brookfield, title Factoring Forms.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-\frac{y+z+i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2})(x-\frac{y+z-i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2})\\=x^2-x(\frac{y+z+z i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2}+\frac{y+z-i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2})+\frac{y+z+i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2}\frac{y+z- i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2} \\
=x^2-x(y+z)+(\frac{y+z}{2})^2-\left(\frac{i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2} \right)^2\\
=x^2-x(y+z)+ \frac{1}{4} \left( (y+z)^2+3(y-z)^2 \right)\\
=x^2-x(y+z)+ \frac{1}{4} \left( 4y^2+4z^2-4yz \right)
$$

Which is your polynomial.

Did you plug in 
$$x_+=\frac{y+z+i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2} \\
x_-=\frac{y+z-i\sqrt{3}(y-z)}{2}
$$
or did you wrongly put them with $\pm$?

Comment: I plug in $(x - \frac {y + z + \sqrt{3} i(y - z)}{2}) (x - \frac{y + z - \sqrt{3} i(y - z)}{2})$. Anyway, Thank you for your answer, I suppose I could've checked by hand, heh.

Comment: Did you write expand in front of it?

Comment: I have done writing $\sqrt{3}i$ as $\sqrt{-3}$ and Now I get it. It is weird, isn't it?

Comment: @AleTolcachier Maybe WA understands i as a variable in this situation :)

Comment: Ohh, I see. I will take in to account for future calculations, thanks!